# Grub not listing the new kernel while booting

Tags: linux, boot, centos, grub, kernel

I recently updated my kernel on CentOS 6.7. That also cleaned up all the older versions, which also updated my /boot/grub/grub.conf, it has a single entry (of the new kernel). Now, when I rebooted, the boot fails with an error "file not found", the reason being, it is still trying to boot with the older kernel, which is not there anymore under /boot. When I go to the list of kernels page, it listed only the older kernel (which again isn't there anymore), no sign of the new kernel in this list. Finally, I had to boot using the grub command line, it worked fine. I have verified /etc/grub.conf, it is a sym link to /boot/grub/grub.conf. There is also one more grub.conf under /boot/efi/EFI/redhat/, but that is also identical to /boot/grub/grub.conf. I searched for the kernel version string to check if it is still referred somewhere, it is not. Then I found out that this was beyond me, something is still not good. Please advice me.

**Update**
This may have something to do with the latest BIOS update, where uefi boot is enabled now. When I manually select the boot drive, I see 2 options one starting with UEFI aaaaaa OS Bootloader and another which starts with SATA aaaaaaaa Boot Drive. When I select the boot drive, it is booting with the latest kernel. Should I modify anything after the BIOS update?

Comment: My experience of `grub` is on Ubuntu, so I don't know how relevant it is, but there is a command `sudo update-grub` which will rebuild the configuration file at any time, especially after calling `/etc/default/grub`. If you don't have this script, all it does is call `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`, so you can use this command instead. However, the normal software update process should call this automatically whenever there is a new kernel and I don't know why this has not happened in your case.

Comment: Do you have a separate boot partition and/or other physical disks (bootable or not) on the system?  It doesn't sound like it's part of the problem here, but it's worth being sure.

Comment: My env still uses the legacy grub (0.97) so there is no option to do grub-mkconfig.

Comment: @MaheshHViraktamath grub legacy does not use `grub.cfg` but `menu.lst`

Comment: @TomYan Thanks for the clarification, my menu.lst is pointing to grub.conf, should it not be a symlink by any chance?

Comment: No idea, what do you mean by pointing?

Comment: @TomYan menu.lst is a sym link..

Comment: I don't see why it should be a symlink. `grub.cfg` and `menu.lst` are of completely different format/syntax/...

Comment: Since it doesn't work anyway, why not just delete the `menu.lst` and see if you can still see a menu when booting?

Comment: @TomYan I tried those things, nothing worked. Now I am trying to boot using the live DVD, but there is no rescue option in the live DVD.

Comment: Deleting the menu.lst is not about "work" or not, but to see what's the actual problem (and/or whether you're REALLY using grub legacy).

Comment: I deleted the menu.lst from /boot/grub/, still the same, after reboot it tries to boot with the old kernel, which is non-existent. Then I have to use the grub command and boot it using the latest kernel.

Answer (score 0):

You're able to boot via grub command line?  Just edit grub.conf to match the fixes you made for your one-time-boot, make a backup, and see below about grub-mkconfig.

---- I re-read and found more details; the below section assumes you couldn't boot ----

Since you cannot boot, you can try two things:  Edit the boot.cfg manually, or boot a rescue-disk/live-cd and run grub-mkconfig.

The first option requires you know the name of the new kernel file or can find it (like with a rescue-disk/live-cd).  Edit /boot/grub/grub.cfg (or press the hotkey at the grub menu to just edit the boot line for one-boot) and find the line that includes "linux [...] vmlinuz[...].  You need to change the vmlinuz section of the line to match the new file name.  If applicable, you'll also need to change the initramfs section to the appropriate new file name.  Save it and see if you can boot (or make the edit in grub and see if it boots, then edit it once you're in.)

grub-mkconfig will obliterate these changes if it doesn't work right, though, so if you work yourself up to something that boots at all, save the working grub.cfg as a backup.

The final step is to ensure that (sudo) grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg will correctly generate the right boot lines.  If you're on a live-cd and haven't managed to boot into the OS yet, use chroot to change root to your actual disk so it picks up the right boot files (and don't forget to mount /boot if it's a separate partition).  Run the command and see if it boots.

The grub-mkconfig step isn't strictly necessary if you manage to make it a bootable system, but it's best practice and updates will probably wreck your boot again if grub-mkconfig isn't functional.

If it turns out grub-mkconfig isn't functional, you'll need to do some diving into /etc/grub(.d) to find which config file isn't behaving properly.  Those configuration files are very complicated to be able to handle many situations, so you can simplify, comment-out and hard-code your own things to make it work for you again.

Good luck.

Comment: My env still uses the legacy grub (0.97) so there is no option to do grub-mkconfig.

Answer (score 0):

> My env still uses the legacy grub (0.97) so there is no option to do grub-mkconfig.

Do you agree for updating fromgrub legacy to grub2?

Then you can update it with apt-get, then:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdX --boot-directory=/your_boot_folder.
```

Then, do the already talked command : sudo grub-update (grub-mkconfig...)